# JAVA: Multiple formats for System.out.format

Tags: java, string, format

I'm attempting to format my double integers to be spaced out, and have two 0's at the end rather then one.

My code:

```
System.out.format(%-10s", double);
```

That works perfectly for spacing out the double for what i'm doing.

I then use

```
System.out.format(%.2f", double);
```

To properly display the double with two integers.

My problem is i can't seem to combine both of these formatters to work on one double. For instance:

```
System.out.format(%-10s %.2f", double);
```

To display something like "{the proper space}  double.00"

They work perfectly when i only use one, but i can't seem to figure out how to use both on the same double. Sorry if i'm vague, i'm very limited on time atm and need to finish this quickly.

Comment: Should you consider using DecimalFormatter class instead/

Comment: Something like `System.out.format("%10.2f%n", 1d);`?

Comment: @MadeProgrammer I get an error when running that

Comment: @Nambari I'm actually using "#0.00" on DecimalFormat atm as a workaround so that DOES in fact work. I just want to see if it's possible to do this with just format. Thanks for attempting to help though!

Comment: AFAIK System format is very generic implementation and what you are looking might not be there. Unless you have restrictions on DecimalFormatter, I would say just go with it.

Comment: Alright Nambari. Thanks for the help again

Answer (score 0):

This code ...

```
System.out.format("<%-10s>\n", "a");
System.out.format("<%10f>\n", 0.2);
System.out.format("<%-10f>\n", 0.2);
System.out.format("<%10.2f>\n", 0.2);
System.out.format("<%-10.2f>\n", 0.2);
```

... shows ...

```
<a         >
<  0,200000>
<0,200000  >
<      0,20>
<0,20      >
```

... is the last one that what you are looking for?